# online algorithm- ski rental

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to solve an online algorithm like ski-rental problem, but the problem is a little different.

The problem is that I have N box, and in each box there are M coin where X < M < Y and can be be different in each different box. I can choose one box and check the number of coins, and I must decide I choose this box or skip it(pay attention that if I skip it I can not come back to this box later).

My objective is select one box so as to maximize the number of coins.

My algorithm is choosing a parameter G, and open first box, and select that box if the number of coins is bigger than G, and in case of did not select any one, I choose the last one anyway.

What should be G to optimize competitive ration against offline solution

Comment: What are X and Y? Given values?

Comment: Please describe your problem well, there are too many ambiguities and I don't know what's the wanted result?

Comment: the X is the number of min. coins which is in each box, and Y is the max number of coins in each box, it means we can not have more than Y coins in each box

Comment: Hi saeed, what is not clear for you?

Comment: X and Y was not clear causes to some other none clear ones, see my answer :)

Comment: can you tune G while running the algorithm?

Comment: No, we cannot change G while running, G is fixed before executing the algorithm

Answer (score 1):

If you know you have N box, you can check first N/e boxes (e=2.7...), and keep track of maximum box (skip all of them just find maximum) now your G=Maximum size, after that select first box which is bigger than G or if no box select last one.

As Chris mentioned in his comment this is [Secretary Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem) and the way I'd offer is optimal solution for this problem, you can see more detail in link, but I don't know If we have a given algorithm what does selecting G means? it depends on input distribution and some additional information.

Comment: thanks saeed jan for your comment, but as I mentioned I have the algorihtm, I can not change it, the only thing which I can do, is change G to obtaine max coin(as I edited the question to make it more clear) (age vaght darid mitoonam ID mo bedam sohbat konim dar moredesh chon be javabesh ehtiaj daram)

Comment: +1 for the optimal solution. This is the secretary problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem . Also, e = 2.71828...

Comment: @mahD I don't know how to change `G` without any affect on algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a constant G, you must assume that your data is prepared by an adversary knowing it. They can give you a box which just causes you to choose it, and then make the last box contain Y, so making the offline algorithm Y/G times more profitable. OTOH they can get you a box which just causes you to decline it, and then make the last box contain X, so making the offline algorithm G/X times more profitable. The least bad G then seems to be sqrt(XY), and in this case the offline algorithm is sqrt(Y/X) times more profitable.

Do you have the option of choosing G at random before receiving the boxes, in which case your adversary knows only its distribution? Based on promising behaviour for the simple example when X = 1, I would then choose ln G uniformly at random between ln X and ln Y, but there are probably better solutions for this case. One way to find them would be to consider only discrete values - which is probably the actual case in this example, and then regard the situation as a zero sum game between you and your adversary.

Comment: @ mcdowella: your answer is almost correct, the part which you said Y/G should be Y/G-1.
can I ask you what is your suggestion for optimal algorithm if we could select K box(in place of 1), and choose the max of k selected box at the end?

Comment: It is difficult to be sure without a specification precise enough to write a scoring computer program (which might be impractically dull) but where you have a maximum of K boxes, it would appear that your adversary can reduce this situation to the previous situation by putting the same number of coins in each of the K boxes.